# Select an item from a combobox using pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to automate a Visual Basic Application using pywinauto, with backend="win32". I am able to handle everything except selecting an item from one of the comboboxes. This particular combobox is dependent upon the selection of another combobox

Here is the code:

```
app.ThunderRT6MDIForm.xxxxx.ComboBox3.select("abc") # this correctly selects from the combobox
app.ThunderRT6MDIForm.xxxxx.ComboBox4.select(1) #This one gives error
```

And the error for the same:

```
IndexError: Combobox has 0 items, you requested item 1 (0 based)
```

Control Identifiers return :

```
        ComboBox - 'abc'    (L136, T206, R376, B227)
       | ['ComboBox3', 'abc co-brandingComboBox2']
       | child_window(title="abc", class_name="ThunderRT6ComboBox")
       | 
       |    | Edit - ''    (L139, T234, R356, B249)
       |    | ['abc co-brandingEdit10', 'Edit12']
       |    | child_window(class_name="Edit")

        ComboBox - ''    (L136, T157, R376, B178)
       | ['4', 'ComboBox4']
       | child_window(class_name="ThunderRT6ComboBox")
       |    | 
       |    | Edit - ''    (L139, T160, R356, B175)
       |    | ['5', 'Edit14']
       |    | child_window(class_name="Edit")
```

Comment: It would seem based on the error that you are trying to select an item by index but the combobox has 0 items in it so there is nothing at index 1. You might have to fire the event first which populates the 2nd combobox

Comment: @majita The first combobox (Combobx3) was populated correctly before trying the second one(Combobox4)

Comment: Does it work after adding `time.sleep(2)` between these actions?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov No, it does not work even after adding a sleep time

Comment: What is the `.class_name()` of the `ComboBox4`? Is it different from `ComboBox3`?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I have now added the control identifiers in the question

Comment: Well, how about trying `backend="uia"` for this particular combo box?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov So should I be launching the application with backend="uia" or is there any other alternative

Comment: `app_uia = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=app_win32.process)` should be enough for this one action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a **temporary workaround** for this problem. I was able to find that pressing Alt + Down key opened the combobox and gave me the list. So, I have used the same logic in code as well and it worked!

```
 app.ThunderRT6MDIForm.xxxxx.ComboBox4.Edit14.type_keys("%{DOWN}")
 app.ThunderRT6MDIForm.xxxxx.ComboBox4.select("item")
```

Comment: Good! Though I don't think this is temporary. :) Because probably this combo box has lazy initialization that performed upon drop down action. So this might be the only way and it's a solution, not a workaround. :)

Comment: By the way, UIA backend can do `.expand()` with the same action without direct typing. But not sure this ExpandCollapsePattern is properly detected by UIA API. Need to try.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variant:

```
loginWindow["Edit1"].type_keys("%{DOWN}")
loginWindow.child_window(title="choiceYouWant", control_type="ListItem").click_input()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use type ahead

If you open the combo box and type the item you want to find then type ‘{ENTER}’

This works even for web applications.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me in a Chrome combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method: (dont fortget to pass combo_box element)

```
def set_combo_box_item_that_starts_with(combo_box, searched_string):
    for text in combo_box.GetProperties()['texts']:
        if text.startswith(searched_string):
            combo_box.select(searched_string)
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn't work for me.

Here's how I implemented it.

```
def comboselect(combo,sel):
    combo.type_keys("{ENTER}")          # Selects the combo box
    texts = combo.texts()               #gets all texts available in combo box
    try:
        index = texts.index(str(sel))   #find index of required selection
    except ValueError:
        return False
    sel_index = combo.selected_index()  # find current index of combo
    if(index>sel_index):
        combo.type_keys("{DOWN}"*abs(index-sel_index))
    else:
        combo.type_keys("{UP}"*abs(index-sel_index))
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..
`

```
 try:
    dlg.child_window(auto_id="XXXX").select(1)
 except:
    pass
```

`